# JavaScript DOM parsing

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So, I got this question in an exam paper and never really figured out how to do it.

I'm aware of how to do basic traversing through a DOM tree but this seemed a bit out of my scope.

Any help would be appreciated.

> Create a JavaScript function which,when called, turns the background color               of all text in `<br>` and `<div>` elements of the HTML page to blue. However, you cannot use `getElementByTagName` here(or any other built in function which finds elements by their names)... instead, you need to traverse the DOM tree element by element. Remember that elements might be nested within other elements.

also jQuery is not allowed... 
**Just to clarify....My problem is I dont know how to write the function to traverse the tree and change background color etc.**

Comment: You parse html to get a DOM. Then your traverse it seek and/or change informations in the DOM, but you won't parse the DOM.

Comment: I used the wrong terminology. Just edited it.

Comment: You don't need to parse the HTML, the browser does that automatically when the DOM is loaded. You just need to write a recursive function that changes the style of an element and then loops to call itself recursively on all the child elements.

Comment: What have you been able to try so far? Can you share a snippet from one of your attempts?

Comment: @Barmar yes, my terminology was incorrect, My problem is I dont know how to write the function to traverse the tree.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I dont really know where to start. I handed up my answer in the exam. My general approach was using leaf nodes to try and get whats in the '<br>' elements

Comment: @conk Which part of the function are you having trouble with? Do you understand recursion?

Comment: @Barmar yes, I suppose I am cofused in how to access the specfic background attribute for the <br> elemets. For example. you have

Comment: `element.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';`

Comment: <p>text<br>text</p> and then something else like <h1>text<br>text<h1>

Comment: how do you specifically generate a function to always get the text in <br> in this case

Comment: Why do you need a function to specifically get the `<br>`? You're just going to iterate over the entire DOM tree, and operate on all the elements equivalently.

Comment: apologies the was a specific part that was somehow left out. If you have a look at the question again I have edited it.

Comment: You can use `if(element.tagName == 'BR' || element.tagName == 'DIV')`

Comment: question states : you cannot use getElementByTagName here(or any other built in function which finds elements by their names)

Comment: There is no text in `<br>`s though

Comment: as in what comes after the <br>. Like <div>text<br> this text to be changed</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this very simple function:

```
function changeBackgroundColor() {
  // predefine our element variable
  var element,
    // get all the nodes in the document
    nodes = document.createNodeIterator(document.documentElement, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT);
  // loop through the nodes
  while(element = nodes.nextNode()) {
    // check if the current node is a "<br />" or "<div />" element
    if(element.tagName.toLowerCase() == "br" || element.tagName.toLowerCase() == "div") {
      // change the background color of the current element
      element.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
  }
}
```

Call the function like this:

```
changeBackgroundColor();
```

Here is some simple HTML that you can test the function on:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>JS DOM Question</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>Hello World!</div>
  <p>Good day World</p>
  <span>Good evening World!</span>
  <i>Good night World!</i>
  <div>Good morning World!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> NOTE: the <br /> element is used to break lines, your not actually supposed to store content in it.

Good luck and all the best.